php-fpm doesn't save error logs for a pool
I'm using php-fpm with Caddy and I cannot make php-fpm log errors. Previously I used nginx and nginx captures and displays php errors in its own logs quite nicely, so I never had an issue, but with caddy I decided to enable php-fpm error log, and it just... doesn't work. But let's start from the beginning:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1
App: Symfony 7.1 with monolog (mentioning it in case it stops error propagation or whatever)
Caddy v2.8.4 config:
[REDACTED] {
  tls [REDACTED]
  root * [REDACTED]
  file_server
  php_fastcgi unix//var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock
  log {
    output file /var/log/caddy/[REDACTED].log
    level ERROR
  }


php-fpm 8.3.12 pool configuration:

listen = /var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock

listen.owner = [REDACTED]
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
user = [REDACTED]
group = www-data
php_value[memory_limit] = 8G
catch_workers_output = yes
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/[REDACTED].log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

The main php-fpm log works just fine, but it just contains information about service restarts basically, so it's not very useful. The log belonging to the pool is not saved.
What I did:

I made sure that permissions and ownership of the log files are correctly set. Log file exists. I touched it, and copy-pasted paths to avoid any typos. The /var/log/php-fpm directory is 777 just as the log file. It's temporary to exclude any permission reasons.
I can see in phpinfo that values set in the pool configuration take effect.
I restarted everything.
When I visit a page returning error 500, no log is saved. The logs file is always empty.


Is there anything else am I missing? Does anyone have any idea where I could look at, to figure this out?

I figured it out. To debug this, I introduced a syntax error in the index.php file. I did this to exclude the possibility of Symfony's meddling, and lo and behold: the error was logged. This indicated that it's Symfony that is using its own error handler.
Basically, in dev environment all errors being logged in the [project's root]/var/logs/dev.log file, as per monolog default configuration:
when@dev:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug
                channels: ["!event"]
            # uncomment to get logging in your browser
            # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
            #firephp:
            #    type: firephp
            #    level: info
            #chromephp:
            #    type: chromephp
            #    level: info
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]

On prod environment though, the logs are being sent to stderr:
when@prod:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: fingers_crossed
                action_level: error
                handler: nested
                excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
                buffer_size: 50 # How many messages should be saved? Prevent memory leaks
            nested:
                type: stream
                path: php://stderr
                level: debug
                formatter: monolog.formatter.json
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
            deprecation:
                type: stream
                channels: [deprecation]
                path: php://stderr
                formatter: monolog.formatter.json

So yeah, Symfony basically handles errors itself, so php-fpm is not logging them.
Here is a post of the Symfony's author about why logging to stderr is recommended: https://symfony.com/blog/logging-in-symfony-and-the-cloud
